# Old series about pink aliens fighting against us, probably aired around 2000

Tags: story-identification

The series was about Earth battling these unknown aliens in space, the war was close to the alien's planet/planets. They wore dark body-suits with dark helmets, completely covering their features. They had better technology than humans, but we were somehow keeping them at bay with tactics. It happened then that one of our pilots crash-landed on one of the alien planets. There, the pilot discovered a pink alien, breeding eggs. They befriended each other and the pilot talked to the alien about Earth's war-tactics. When he got rescued, it came out that the pink alien is in fact one of the enemy aliens without the body suit, and that the alien had divulged the war-tactics to his leaders, causing the humans to start loosing all the battles.

I also remember that one of the humans tried putting on one of the alien's helmets. It made a sucking noise and the human nearly died from suffocation (the aliens breathed something else than air).

Any help with the name would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The series you're looking for is [*Space: Above and Beyond*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space:_Above_and_Beyond). It describes the war between humanity and the alien Chigs. The Chigs breathe a methane atmosphere, and are revealed in the series finale to be descended from bacteria that originated on Earth. As such, their war effort is seen by them as a defensive war to reclaim their homeworld. It was an underrated series that was cancelled after only a single season. The episode you're remembering is actually the second-last episode of the series, and one of the best.

Comment: Thank you, I see a couple of users marked my question as a duplicate question as well.

Comment: The humans did not start losing all the battles.  After the advance team warned the alien tending the eggs that the war would soon spread to the planet, the aliens initiated peace negotiations, because that planet was sacred to them.  The negotiator said through a translator "It is where we go to be born."

Comment: @WillFeldman: And it turned out that the monopolistic arms and spacecraft manufacturer that acted as a sort of de facto government of humanity had known about the Chigs for nine years, after launching a satellite through a wormhole that ended up on the Chig birthworld. Good cliffhanger, so it's too bad the series was cancelled.